# In api.ai when an 'isList' parameter is sent to the webhook, what format is it in?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I'm used to C# not JS, so cut me some slack if I'm ignorant but I'm looking to do a foreach loop through a list sent from API.ai, and I don't know whether it's a fixed length array or a List, or if there's even the distinction between the two in Javascript.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, however JavaScript does not have List/Array data types similar to C# ones. There are however Arrays and Objects and your API call most likely will return an array of objects however I have never came across API.ai so I won't give my hand for that.

An object is in JSON format, you can check how many objects are in the array using `.length()` function on the array.

With sample response from the API such as this:

```
[{
   title : "Title 1",
   context : "Context 1"
},
{
   title : "Title 2",
   context : "Context 2"
}]
```

You can do a simple for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
   response[i] // Object 
}
```

Note how I left `response[i]`, you then can access properties of the given object such as `response[i].title` or `response[i].context`.

On a side note & as a heads up, you might need to parse your returned value as JSON before looping, all depends on your code.

Edit worth noting:

Response might contain a property which has an array of objects assigned, the object would look similar to:

```
[{
   title : "Title 1",
   context : "Context 1",
   prop : [{ val : "val 1", name : "val 1" }]
},
{
   title : "Title 2",
   context : "Context 2",
   prop : [{ val : "val 2", name : "val 2" }]
}]
```

To iterate over the inner array (prop field) a simple modification to our for loop above:

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < response[i].prop.length(); j++){
      response[i].prop[j] // Inner Object 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I looked into the JSON file that's sent with it, and you're right it's a simple array to iterate through.